# Angular JSONP calling WordPress JSON REST API

Tags: wordpress, angularjs, jsonp

I'm not entirely sure what's going on, as I'm still trying to figure cross domain javascript calls, but I'm calling some JSON from a WordPress site (that's using the WordPress JSON REST API plugin). Since it's coming from a local site (I'm working on a mobile app using Ionic/Angular), I've had some cross-domain access issues. So, I'm looking at using JSONP.

I've successfully called and returned info, but I can't seem to do anything with the returned data.

My call is as so:

```
$http.jsonp('http://heavymetalhamilton.ca/wp-json/hmh-api/shows?_jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

However, nothing is being logged. I can see that the $http.jsonp call is returning data (I can see in developer tools and looks like this:

```
/**/([{"ID":30,"post_date":"2014-09-25 18:33:15","post_date_gmt":"2014-09-25 
...
)
```

I see that the returning data has some packing around it, but I'm not sure how to process this data.

Any help?

EDIT: Have what's happening going on in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvFHL)

Comment: If nothing is logged then the request must have failed. Try `$http.jsonp('…').error(function (data, status, headers, config) { … … })`

Comment: It does hit the error... and shows a status of 404. Very strange, since dev tools are showing the request returned a status of 200 as well as data.

Comment: Is there anything else shown? Such as error message or the exception thrown? Status codes are not reliable when using JSONP requests.

Comment: No exceptions - just undefined data.

Comment: So, I kind of have this working, but I'm not really sure why. I'm not sure how I can keep the callback function happen inside the controller so that I can continue to use the scope that's available... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvFHL

Comment: This is exactly the error I'm getting: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-jsonp-to-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the biggest problem I had (there were a couple), was my jsonp call. There isn't a "success" promise attached to it. Jsonp fires a function defined as a callback - in this case, the call to:

http://heavymetalhamilton.ca/wp-json/hmh-api/shows?_jsonp=mytest&callback=JSON_CALLBACK

calls a global function of mytest() once returned. So, in order to get a global function in my controller, so I can use $scope, my end result is:

```
$http.jsonp('http://heavymetalhamilton.ca/wp-json/hmh-api/shows?_jsonp=mytest&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');

window.mytest = function(data) {
  $scope.shows = data;
};
```

I also had an issue with the content type I was returning (as mentioned by @Miszy). I have to specify that the Content-Type is set to application/javascript... previously it was returning application/json.

In my case, I'm writing some custom functionality to return specific content, so I added the following:

```
if ($_GET['_jsonp']) {
   $response->header( 'Content-Type', 'application/javascript; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), true );
}
```

Hope this helps someone down the road!

Answer (score -1):

The data returns as a JSON object. Please try to log using the following format

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Or else you can go through the returned data set in the following manner

```
console.log(data.ID + ', ' + data.post_date);
```

and so on...

Comment: How exactly `JSON.stringify` is to help here? `console.log` is fine with string or object - the problem is it's never getting called.

Comment: The success is not being called, which is the issue.